# what does E represent in microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel

Excel has just output this trendline: y = 0.032x4 - 5608.x3 + 4E+08x2 - 1E+13x + 1E+17

How can I convert this equation into a useable form without the E's.

(how do you interpret these E's)

Comment: Have a [read](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-numbers-in-scientific-exponential-notation-f85a96c0-18a1-4249-81c3-e934cd2aae25) here =)

Comment: This is basic maths not only Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trendline from a graph in an equation, but, in addition to translating it correctly, you need to also format the trendline to show a maximum number of decimals (e.g 15), else your results will not be congruent with the graph.

Your formula would translate into something like:

```
y = 0.032*(x^4) - 5608*(x^3) + 4E+08*(x^2) + 1E+13*(x) + 1E+17
```

- `4E+08` will be interpreted by Excel as being `4*10^8` or `400,000,000`. You don't have to do that yourself,

However, unless you have a very old version of Excel, where the `LINEST` function did not work properly, it is usually simpler to just use worksheet functions for that purpose.

For example, if this is a line graph where **y** is your range of y-values; your trendline is a 4th order polynomial, and your x-axis is just serial numbers 1..n, you could use:

```
=LINEST($A$4:$A$12,SEQUENCE(COUNT(y))^{1,2,3,4})
```

to return your sequence of m values.

And to return a point along the curve, you could use

```
=SUM(LINEST($A$4:$A$12,SEQUENCE(COUNT(y))^{1,2,3,4})*A4^{4,3,2,1,0})
```

where `A4` represents a new_x value.

If you don't have the `SEQUENCE` function, there are a variety of other functions that can be used to generate a sequence of values; or you can just select your known_x's (*which you would have to do anyway if they are not sequential `{1..n}`*)

Answer (score 0):

> The Scientific format displays a number in exponential notation,
>   replacing part of the number with E+n, in which E (exponent)
>   multiplies the preceding number by 10 to the nth power. For example, a
>   2-decimal scientific format displays 12345678901 as 1.23E+10, which is
>   1.23 times 10 to the 10th power.

**Before**

```
y = 0.032x4 - 5608.x3 + 4E+08x2 - 1E+13x + 1E+17
```

**After**

```
y = 0.032x4 - 5608.x3 + 4 x 10^8x * 2 - 1 * 10^13x + 1 * 10^17
```

Basically really large numbers,`4 x 10^8x*2=400000000x*2, 1 x 10^13x=10000000000000x, 1E+17=100000000000000000`

Comment: Can you show me how to convert my equqtion as an example. Thanks

Comment: Sure, give me a sec